# Getting script by Ajax from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser-cache

I have following ajax call:

```
request = $.ajax({
    context : this,
    dataType : "html",
    cache : true,
    url : "ajaxContent.html",
    success : function(results) {
        jQuery("#result").html(results);
        }
});
```

and html ajaxContent.html looks like that:

```
<p>some conent</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="someScript.js" />
```

**problem**

Everytime when I am calling ajax I am also calling someScript.js?=[timestamp].
I would like to download someScript.js from cache - so I want to remove that timestamp from url. How could i do that?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: A jsfiddle would help, because right now I don't see how you're getting `someScript.js?=[timestamp]`.

Comment: Also, why don't you load <script type="text/javascript" src="someScript.js" /> before any ajax call is done? Make it contain functions, and you can call those functions from your ajaxContent.html instead of including a new script tag every time.

Comment: @HamzaKubba I uploaded screenshot. I don't want to load whole javascript before ajax, because i don't know which js file will be needed to perform some actions which user can do on loaded site. I want to make app with high performance so I am loading exactly what user will use.

Answer (score 0):

In your outer javascript, have some simple code like this:

```
var loaded = {};

function loadScript (scriptName) {
    if (!(scriptName in loaded)) {
         loaded[scriptName] = true;

         var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
         var script= document.createElement('script');
         script.type= 'text/javascript';
         script.src= scriptName;
         head.appendChild(script);
    }
}
```

and, in your `ajaxContent.html`, change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadScript("someScript.js");
</script>
```

Comment: Close enough, but.. In my .js files I have duplicated methods. ex.: jQuery("form").submit(function(){/*some action*/}). So when user call other html file by ajax I need to reload .js. I just want to load it directly from browser cache.

Comment: Then put those methods inside functions and call them after loading: `<script type="text/javascript"> loadScript("someScript.js"); doSomething();</script>`